# Overloaded ( << ) friend function, can't access public class data

Tags: c++, class, matrix, operator-overloading, istream

I can't seem to access class variables through functions or otherwise, side of my overloaded << friend function. Values appear to be random numbers inside of the functions even though I redefine them in the main.

I am in the process of making a program that does various matrix functions using overloaded operators. Right now I am trying to make the functions work with matrices of sizes that aren't 3x3 and these worked earlier with the global variable `s`, but I would like `rows` to be redefined before `<<` and `>>` are called.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define s 3
class Matrix
{
private:

public:
    int rows,cols;
    int rows1, rows2, cols1, cols2;
    int **m;
    void setRows(int rowsa);
    int getRows();
    Matrix()
    {
        m = new int *[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            m[i] = new int[10];
        }
    }
    friend Matrix operator+(Matrix &m1, Matrix &m2);
    friend Matrix operator-(Matrix &m1, Matrix &m2);
    friend Matrix operator*(Matrix &m1, Matrix &m2);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Matrix &m1);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &is, Matrix &m1);
};

Matrix operator+(Matrix &m1, Matrix &m2)
{
    Matrix m3 = Matrix();

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
            m3.m[i][j] = m1.m[i][j] + m2.m[i][j];
    }
    return m3;
}
Matrix operator-(Matrix &m1, Matrix &m2)
{
    Matrix m3 = Matrix();

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
            m3.m[i][j] = m1.m[i][j] - m2.m[i][j];
    }
    return m3;
}

Matrix operator*(Matrix &m1, Matrix &m2)
{
    Matrix m3 = Matrix();
    Matrix rix;
    for (int i = 0; i < rix.rows1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rix.cols2; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < rix.cols1; k++)
            {
                m3.m[i][j] = m1.m[i][k] * m2.m[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return m3;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Matrix &m)
{
    Matrix rix;
    for (int i = 0; i < rix.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rix.cols; j++)
            os << m.m[i][j] << " ";
        os << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}
istream &operator>>(istream &is, Matrix &m1)
{
    //overloaded >> to input the values of a matrix
// PROBLEM IS HERE
    Matrix rix;

    cout<<"value of rows1"<<rix.rows1<<endl;
    cout<<"value of rows"<<rix.rows<<endl;
    cout<<"value of getRows"<<rix.getRows()<<endl;

    int k;
    for (int i = 0; i < rix.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rix.cols; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter element "
                 << "(" << i << "," << j << "): ";
            cin >> k;
            m1.m[i][j] = k;
        }
    }
}
void Matrix::setRows(int rowsa){
    rows= rowsa;
}
int Matrix::getRows(){
    return rows;
}
int main()
{
    int rosx;
    Matrix m1 = Matrix();
    Matrix m2 = Matrix();
    Matrix rix;

    cout << "Number of rows for the first Matrix? (max 10)" << endl;
    cin >> rix.rows1;

    cout << "Number of columns for the first Matrix? (max 10)" << endl;
    cin >> rix.cols1;

    cout << "Number of rows for the second Matrix? (max 10)" << endl;
    cin >> rix.rows2;

    cout << "Number of columns for the second Matrix? (max 10)" << endl;
    cin >> rix.cols2;

    cout << "input the elements of the first matrix: " << endl;
    rix.setRows(rix.rows1);
    cout <<rix.rows;
    cin >> m1;

    cout << m1;

    cout << "input the elements of the second matrix: " << endl;
    rix.rows = rix.rows2;

    rix.cols = rix.cols2;
    cin >> m2;
    cout << m2;

    Matrix m3 = m1 * m2;
    cout << "output" << endl;
    cout << m3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about declaring a new Matrix at the start of your input and output functions. In your input you have a perfectly good Matrix `m1`. It's rows and columns haven't been set to anything, so iterating over them doesn't make sense, but that's the Matrix you should be using.

Answer (score 3):

Your values are garbage because your constructor doesn't give any values to your variables.

```
Matrix()
{
    m = new int *[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        m[i] = new int[10];
    }
}
```

Nowhere in this constructor do you give a values to `rows`, `cols`, `rows1`, `rows2`, `cols1` or `cols2.` So it's not surprising that they have garbage values.

I suppose it should be

```
Matrix()
{
    m = new int *[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        m[i] = new int[10];
    }
    rows = 10;
    cols = 10;
}
```

Although I don't understand why you have three rows variables and three cols variables.

Another misunderstanding is that you have two variables called `rix`

```
int main()
{
    int rosx;
    Matrix m1 = Matrix();
    Matrix m2 = Matrix();
    Matrix rix; // one variable called rix

istream &operator>>(istream &is, Matrix &m1)
{
    //overloaded >> to input the values of a matrix
// PROBLEM IS HERE
    Matrix rix; // another variable called rix
```

Clearly you think they are the same variable, but they are not. Two variables in different functions are different variables **even if they have the same name**.

Here's another misunderstanding

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Matrix &m)
{
    Matrix rix;
    for (int i = 0; i < rix.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rix.cols; j++)
            os << m.m[i][j] << " ";
        os << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}
```

For some reason you've written this function to print out the variable `m` but using the rows and columns from a totally different variable called `rix`. That doesn't make any sense. The rows and columns should come from the variable `m`, since that is the matrix you are trying to print.

Really I'm just scratching the surface. This code is full of misunderstandings. You need to review how C++ works. In particular how constructors work, how variables work, and just think a little more logically about the code you are writing. It has to make sense.

I would start again. It will be better code second time around.

Comment: @Gomi, thow it's very nice of you to thank the poster of a good answer to your question, the correct way to show appreciation is to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel like it solved your problem.